# how to get the values of form in javascript and calculate the values and display answer at same page?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the values from radio buttons and input fields  and quantity fields and calculate them display on the same page the below images are my questions

Comment: Welcome to SO, in order to get the best answers I would recommend reading this first: [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include in the question the code you've written *as text* (there are code formatting options in the question editor), or even better as a runnable code snippet, to demonstrate the problem you're having.  Also, please describe the problem.  "I want to ..." isn't really a description of what isn't working or where you're stuck.  Be specific.  To learn more about how to ask a good question, please read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Post your questions with code samples. That way the community can see what you are working with. It also helps visualizing the problem.

Anyway, I am going to assume that you are working with HTML/JS. If you are working with some back-end, i.e. PHP, NodeJS, etc. then there are other ways to achieve the result. However, since you haven't specified, here is an example based on purely HTML and JS.

Have your form and a hidden result `div` in the same HTML. Put the `div` where you want to show the answer, for example below your image.

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="price">Price:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="25"><br>
    <label for="qty">Qty:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" value="5"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="myResults" class="myResults" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Results</h3>
    <p>Subtotal <span id="subtotalDisplay"></span></p>
</div>
```

Notice that I did not put `action` and `method` attributes for the `<form>` element. So, this form submission will not go anywhere else.

In the JS, do your data retrieval and calculations inside the form's submit listener. Put your results in any element inside the hidden `div` and then show the div.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    let formElement = document.forms.myForm;
    let resultDiv = document.getElementById('myResults');

    formElement.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData(formElement); // build form data
        let price = formData.get('price'); // get form field values
        let qty = formData.get('qty');
        let subtotal = parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty);
        console.log('subtotal', subtotal);
        document.getElementById('subtotalDisplay').innerHTML = subtotal; // put your results where they need to be
        resultDiv.style.display = 'inherit'; // make the hidden div visible.
    });

});
```

I hope this helps.